# Quantum mechanics for extremely large objects

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

I was thinking, classical physics describes moderately sized objects and that breaks down at really small scales and so we had to work out quantum physics to explain this, but is there any reason to believe that maybe things will break again when we go to really really really large scales?

Comment: The general special relativity is good for large-scale objects.

Comment: Quantum mechanics should apply at all scales. But for large objects the quantum corrections to the classical solution are generally negligibly small.

Comment: Then you might see peculalar effects when you look at M51, or whatever your own personal favorite galaxy happens  is be. But we don't .

Comment: Well there's dark energy.     But I think you're looking at it in the wrong way.   Quantum effects are individual particles behaving in what some might call, unexpected ways.   Classical physics is observed behavior of structures of gazillions of particles bound together into, say, an apple, that falls as fast as gravity says it should.     There isn't a "next step" as things grow larger unless you count things like Neutron Stars that overcome the EM force by gravity or Dark Energy that overcomes Gravity over great distances, but I don't see that as the same type of change.

Comment: Dark energy might be the energy of the spacetime vacuum, or some sort of field that has a nonzero vacuum energy. That's an inherently quantum gravity problem. Something definitely breaks at small enough sizes, the Planck length, and is reflected in gravity in the large.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing so far has indicated a problem at large distances.

An experiment was performed to see if photons arriving from Betelguese at widely (100m?) separated locations could be combined in a interferometer. Although the photons had travelled over 600 light years, the photons still interfered as you would expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum mechanics relies on the Idea that a lot of stuff is quantized (meaning that stuff always exists in integral multiples of a particular quantity which you call the Quantum of the quantity). These quanta even for our day to day SI units are extremely small and often for most practical purposes can be neglected. So on astronomical scales where numbers are unimaginably huge like billions of kilometers quantization has no practical effect. But that doesn't mean that Quantum mechanics breaks down at astronomical scales It is still valid (and will probably remain so for a long time) only it's effects are so small compared to the enormously big scales we are dealing with that for all practical purposes we can neglect it.